# Route [method] not defined laravel 5.3, but when i use URL::to the error gone

Tags: php, laravel

I got stuck with this error route not defined, here is my route:

`{{route('admin.users.edit',$user->id)}}`

I defined this route in my master admin blade page, but if I changed the route to `URL::to` it works but does not redirect me to my edit page.

Here is my defined controller:

```
Route::resource('admin/users', 'AdminUsersController');
```

Comment: run "php artisan route:list" from your terminal

Comment: i did and the route is listed, my issue is when i use route function it shows me not defined route

Comment: Add the output of php artisan route:list in your question

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this :

```
{{ route('admin.users.edit', [$user->id]) }}
```

Hope this work for you!